# Google AI Platform: confused about the multiple runtime versions I have to specify

Tags: tensorflow, runtime, google-api-python-client, object-detection-api, google-ai-platform

From the training up to the prediction phase in Google AI Platform Training and Prediction, there is this notion of runtime version and I'm a little bit confused about it. A runtime version must be specified when you launch the training (see [here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/versioning#:%7E:text=AI%20Platform%20Training%20supports%20each,that%20use%20the%20runtime%20version.)). Another one has to be specified when you export your model in Tensorflow SavedModel format and another one when you create a versioned model.

Example. I submit a training job using the [Google APIs Client Library for Python](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/python-client-library) so I followed this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/training-jobs) to configure my training job. As I'm using the [tensorflow object-detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection), my config file looks like:

```
{
"jobId": "...",
"trainingInput": {
    "runtimeVersion": "2.1",
    "pythonVersion": "3.7",
    "scaleTier": "CUSTOM",
    "masterType": "standard",
    "workerCount": "1",
    "workerType": "cloud_tpu",
    "workerConfig": {
        "tpuTfVersion": "1.15"
    },
    "region": "us-central1",
    "jobDir": "...",
    "pythonModule": "object_detection.model_main_tf2",
    "args": [
        "--model_dir",
        "...",
        "--pipeline_config_path",
        "..."
    ]
  }
}
```

Following that my config file for the exportation:

```
{
"jobId": "...",
"trainingInput": {
    "runtimeVersion": "2.1",
    "pythonVersion": "3.7",
    "scaleTier": "CUSTOM",
    "masterType": "standard",
    "workerCount": "1",
    "workerType": "standard",
    "region": "us-central1",
    "pythonModule": "object_detection.exporter_main_v2",
    "args": [
        "--input_type",
        "image_tensor",
        "--pipeline_config_path",
        "...",
        "--trained_checkpoint_dir",
        "...",
        "--output_directory",
        "..."
    ]
  }
}
```

See I had to specify again a runtime version. Does it have to be the same as the runtime version used for the training job? For the last part, after having created the model, I had to create a version. My config file:

```
{
"name": "v1",
"description": "version description",
"isDefault": "False",
"deploymentUri": "...",
"createTime": "string",
"runtimeVersion": "2.1",
"machineType": "mls1-c1-m2",
"framework": "TENSORFLOW",
"pythonVersion": "3.7"
```

}

Again a runtime version. Same question: does it have to be the same as those used before? Or can the runtime for training and prediction be different?